# How to create a DAWG?

Tags: c++, data-structures

How can a **[DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAWG)** be created? I have found that there are two ways; one is converting a trie into a dawg and the other being creating a new DAWG straight away? Which one is the easiest? Can you please elaborate on the two and provide some links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to think about the DAWG is as a minimum-state DFA for all of the words in your word list.  As a result, the traditional algorithm for constructing a DAWG is the following:

1. Start off by constructing a trie for the collection of words.
2. Add a new node to the trie with edges from itself to itself on all inputs.
3. For each missing letter transition in the trie, add a transition from the start node to this new dead node.
4. (At this point, you now have a (probably non-minimum) **[DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton)** for the set of words.)
5. Minimize the DFA using **[the standard algorithm for DFA state minimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization)**.

Once you have done this, you will be left with a DAWG for the set of words you are interested in.

The runtime of this algorithm is as follows.  Constructing the initial DFA can be done by constructing a trie for all the original words (which takes time O(n), where n is the total number of characters in all the input strings), then filling in the missing transitions (which takes time O(n|Σ|), where |Σ| is the number of different characters in your alphabet).  From there, the minimization algorithm runs in time O(n<sup>2</sup> |Σ|).  This means that the overall runtime for the algorithm is O(n<sup>2</sup> |Σ|).

To the best of my knowledge, there is no straightforward algorithm for incrementally constructing DAWGs.  Typically, you would build a DAWG for a set of words only if you already had all the words in advance.  Intuitively, this is true because inserting a new word that has some suffixes already present in the DAWG might require a lot of restructuring of the DAWG to make certain old accepting states not accepting and vice-versa.  Theoretically speaking, this results because inserting a new word might dramatically change the equivalence classes of the DFA's distinguishability relation, which might require substantial changes to the DFA's structure.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am constructing a dawg for a dictionary? So point being i should basically build a trie first? If thats the case it would get easier because i have some references for creating a trie in a book? And i didn't completely understand the algorithm. Some visual help would be appreciated or a link maybe. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: @UsmanAmjed- I don't have any visualizations for the DFA minimization algorithm, since the algorithm is somewhat complicated.  However, it's honestly not all that hard to code up.  As for constructing tries - I would **strongly** suggest not trying to code up a DAWG until you feel comfortable working with tries.  Tries are much simpler than DAWGs and give the same performance guarantees, but with a much higher memory overhead.  I would suggest reading up on them first.

Comment: Yeah i would. I am constructing a dictionary of around 500000 words; would the memory overhead be huge? Should i even go for dawgs? Are the very different from tries as far as traversing etc are concerned?

Comment: @UsmanAmjed- The trie is definitely going to have a huge memory overhead compared to the DAWG in this case, so compressing the words would be useful.  Depending on your application, though, you might be better off using a hash table or some other structure.

Comment: It is a  text predictor with auto complete; auto correct and spell checker fucnctions

Comment: What kind of system are you running this on? My "small" computer has 4GB of ram, 500000 [ten times more than an average oxford english dictionary!] words with an average length of 10 characters and about 30 bytes overhead in the data structure still only makes 15MB - not like you need the 16GB my large computer has to cope with that.

Comment: @MatsPetersson- Oh whoops, I read that as five million, not five hundred thousand.  I was thinking five million strings x ten chars per string x 26 pointers per node x 4-8 bytes per pointer, which is pushing it.  But if I'm off by a factor of ten, that looks a lot more reasonable.

Comment: @templatetypedef You can absolutely construct a dawg directly from a list of words, this is the standard goto paper, you can do it easier if the list is initially sorted, however it is possible if the list is unsorted also: http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/J00-1002.pdf

Comment: @rossb83 I stand corrected! Thanks for sharing!