# how to build a DAWG graphique in Java

Tags: java, search, optimization, data-structures, dawg

I need to create a `DAWG` graphic for my scrabble IA.

After multi search I found two or three sites that explain how to create a `DAWG`:

https://progaide.com/question/12331755-algorithme-de-cr-ation-de-dawg-facile

[How to create a DAWG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025709/how-to-create-a-dawg)

https://codes-sources.commentcamarche.net/faq/10903-compression-d-un-dictionnaire-sous-forme-de-dawg

However, I don't understand it really well.

I need to create this graph with a dictionary in .txt (approximately 400.000 word like a french dictionary) to optimize a search of the different words that existe in the French Language.

Now I have a simple search in my .txt but it is really slow and i think that the real good method to implement this, is a `DAWG`.

My IA can put the first word with the letter of player1 but for the other turn of play i need to analyze a word with 8 letter and not 7, and i think the best option before advanced is optimize my research. For me, the best solution is a `DAWG` but if you have any other solution, I am open minded.

Thanks for reading me, I hope my english is understandable.

PS: if one need the .txt, I can give it to you. No problem (is a real full french dictionary for scrabble)

Comment: Hi nicolas welcome to SO, your question seems to be a bit generic, what have you tried to implement DAWG?

Comment: Thanks you, i am very thankful  for all the help you can find on this forum.                  For now I am just looking for some information, on order to fully understand what is a DAWG, and know if it’s the right tool to use to implement my existing word research?
If it is a good idea to use DAWG to implement it, I am wondering what is the best way to implement it in java : indeed, there are no concret exemple online...

Comment: During this week, i continuss me search about this type of DAWG and i found this if any one is interest :http://www.wutka.com/dawg.html?fbclid=IwAR1CyXSI4Ox8_sYpTSQ26CreU4OY-3tqbcxlkTQh1xQMRTjgI-2zoVirkOo, really interest for undertand how implement a DAWG. I will begin the code during this week-end, i come-back if me graph works.